# Missing scope within Object.keys

Tags: javascript

I'm getting confused, I'm loosing scope within my Object.keys(foo).forEach function and I'm not sure why. Here's the code:

```
...
var that = this;
items.forEach(function(value, key) { 
   ...
   Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
      that._someFunction();
   }, that);
});
```

Within items.forEach everything is fine, I can access that, but within the Object.keys... that is gone, what's wrong here?

Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: Use an ES6 arrow function instead `Object.keys(value).foreach(key => {...})`

Comment: Try using arrow functions all the way through, and you have a typo on `foreach`should be `forEach` - `items.forEach(value => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
        this._someFunction(key);
    });
});`

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem. Your code would work: https://jsfiddle.net/h8monjhk/ - In both `.forEach()` branches `that` has the same value (`test` in the fiddle)

Comment: @Olian04 can't use this, cause it's in UI5 context and ES6 is not supported yet...

Comment: Ok guys, I'm not sure, why this wasn't working before, but after a retest it's absolutly fine now! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can not use ES6, you can write something like:

```
items.forEach( (function(value, key) { 
   ...
   Object.keys(value).forEach((function(key) {
      this._someFunction();
   }).bind(this), this);
}).bind(this));
```